# Breaking down save/load functions into modules (.c, .h, .o) files

Tags: c, function

I have a task for my project, that I have to take my saving and loading functions and write them in a different module. It sounds like this -

> "Write those functions in a different `.c` file, create a header file (`.h`) and an object file (`.o`), used for working with that module."

I had close to NONE experience with those header and object files, and I do not clearly understand why do I even need them?

How I understand is I would just smash those save/load functions into a different `.c` file and include it in my main program, what are the (`.h`) and (`.o`) files for? And what do I write in them?

These are my functions:

```
int loadUsersData(int balance) {
    int size, savedBalance;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("save.bin", "rb");
    fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    if(size != 0) {
        fread(&savedBalance, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        balance = savedBalance;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return balance;
}
```

And:

```
void saveUsersData(int balance) {
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("save.bin", "wb");
    printf("Saving...\n");
    fwrite(&balance, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    printf("Successfully saved!\nSee you next time!");
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: This is a question for your C textbook. One thing is that this `*.o` does not make sense much, as it is an output of the compilation, and in general is not "maintained".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not clearly understand why do I even need them?

You need header files to get the function prototypes and other declarations.

Yes, you could just include a .c file in your main file with the main method. This would have several effects:

1. You get a huge, maybe over hundreds of thousands/millions of lines of code. Recompiling would take a long time.
2. You would compile the same function times==> Multiple definitions, although this could be fixed by using `static`.

Another usage is for example encapsulation:

```
struct someOpaqueType;
typedef struct someOpaqueType * OpaqueType;
```

This shows, that the user of the header file just shouldn't care about/see the contents of `struct someOpaqueType`.

> what are the (.h) and (.o) files for?

Header(.h) files contain definitions, declarations and function prototypes.

Object files (.o) contain your compiled C code, that wasn't linked to an executable. These is the output file format if you use `-c`(gcc/clang).
Furthermore it contains things like debug infos, relocation data, ...

> And what do I write in them?

For example

```
#ifndef USER_DATA //This include guard is there to make it only included once per translation unit.
#define USER_DATA
//Function protoype.
int loadUsersData(int);
void saveUsersData(int);
#endif
```

or, if you want to use non-standard extensions:

```
#pragma once
int loadUsersData(int);
void saveUsersData(int);
```